# xml as a property of my class

Tags: c#, xml

I have a class has some properties and one of that properties want to get or set XML text, something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Root>
  <SaveCode>QuiddityVer</SaveCode>
  <IsMainProject>fals</IsMainProject>
  <DesignerItems>
    <DesignerItem>
      <Quiddity>Play</Quiddity>
      <Name>Node_Play1</Name>            
      <LoopBodyInDesignerCanvas />
    </DesignerItem>   
</Root>
```

what is the proper Variable type for set and get this xml expresion?

and my property of my class is something like this:

```
privte String _myxmlExpresion;
public String myxmlExpresion
        {
            get
            {
                return _myxmlExpresion;
            }
            set
            {
                _myxmlExpresion= value;
            }
        }
```

my project is multiTab, and each of that Tabs has DesignerItems to show some nodes in it(some thing like Visual DialPlan, or Visual VXML Designer) and some node has property that is open a new tab when I click it, and I save and open this tabs in XML file,but here I dont want this new tab to extra xml file, I want to save it in my property.

Comment: You should be deserializing this into a concrete type and using that as your property.

Comment: sorry..but i cant understand your question..do you want extract content from the xml and if yes what do you want to extract

Comment: What do you want to do with it?  Are you just going to print it to the screen?  Are you going to need to look into the structure and find certain items?  Will you be making small changes to what's there and then saving it back?  This will help determine if you need to create a set of custom types to represent this, just use XML libraries to query it, or if you can just leave it as a string.

Comment: How do you plan to use this property? Show a couple use-cases.

Comment: I don't want to save XML expression to a file, I want to have property has my XML expression.

Comment: what is the proper type that property

Answer (score 2):

You could use either just a plain string, or an [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx).

Alternatively, you could also use an [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx). (thanks msmucker0527)

Comment: Or an XmlDocument : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx

Comment: @msmucker0527 Indeed. Added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Create class for holding your xml data:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string SaveCode { get; set; }
    public bool IsMainProject { get; set; }
    public List<DesignerItem> DesignerItems { get; set; }
}

public class DesignerItem
{
    public string Quiddity { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LoopBodyInDesignerCanvas { get; set; }
}
```

And parse your xml:

```
XElement root = XElement.Parse(xml);
var foo = new Foo()
{
    SaveCode = (string)root.Element("SaveCode"),
    IsMainProject = (bool)root.Element("IsMainProject"),
    DesignerItems = root.Element("DesignerItems")
                        .Elements("DesignerItem")
                        .Select(di => new DesignerItem()
                        {
                            Quiddity = (string)di.Element("Quiddity"),
                            Name = (string)di.Element("Name"),
                            LoopBodyInDesignerCanvas = (string)di.Element("LoopBodyInDesignerCanvas")
                        }).ToList()
};
```

Store parsed object as a property of type `Foo` (of course I think there is a better name for data, which your xml holds). This will give you all advantages of strongly-typed language:

```
if (yourObject.Foo.IsMainProject)
    // ...
```

*BTW* You have typos in xml - there is no closing tag for `DesignerItems` element. And there is typo in `false` value.

Comment: Your code is excellent but I don't that mean. I want to have property set and get something like string, but my data for setting and getting is not string but it is XML Expression

Comment: @Ahadaghapour why would you store plain xml in .net objects?

Comment: I want to save a xml file as property of my class

Comment: And what you are going to do next with saved xml file?

Comment: my project is multiTab, and each of that Tabs has DesignerItems to show some nodes in it(some thing like Visual DialPlan) and some node has property that is generate a new tab, and I save and open this tabs in XML file,but herer I dont want this new tab to extra xml file, I want to save it in my property.

Comment: my project is multiTab, and each of that Tabs has DesignerItems to show some nodes in it(some thing like Visual DialPlan, or Visual VXML Designer) and some node has property that is open a new tab when I click it, and I save and open this tabs in XML file,but here I dont want this new tab to extra xml file, I want to save it in my property.

Answer (score 0):

one of the appropriate way is to save all new tab as a separate file and have new tabs address in our property to open and save XML document.